# Proper usage of std::move

Tags: c++, pointers

The following code works:

```
class Handler {
public:
    Application* application;

    bool handle(sf::Event&);
};

class TestApp {
public:
    TestApp();

    bool running;
    void run();
    void attach_handler(Handler*);

    std::forward_list<std::unique_ptr<Handler>> handlerFList;
};

TestApp::TestApp() {
}

void Application::run() {
    while (running) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window->pollEvent(event)) {
            for (auto& handler : handlerFList) {
                if (handler->handle(event)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void Application::attach_handler(Handler* handler) {
    handlerFList.push_front(std::unique_ptr<Handler>(std::move(handler)));
    handler->application = this;
}

int main() {
    sqt::TestApp app;

    sqe::HandlerClose hc;
    app.attach_handler(&hc);

    app.run();
    return 0;
}
```

But this one does not:

```
class Handler {
public:
    Application* application;

    bool handle(sf::Event&);
};

class TestApp {
public:
    TestApp();

    bool running;
    void run();
    void attach_handler(Handler*);

    std::forward_list<std::unique_ptr<Handler>> handlerFList;
};

TestApp::TestApp() {
    sqe::HandlerClose hc;
    attach_handler(&hc);
}

void TestApp::run() {
    while (running) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window->pollEvent(event)) {
            for (auto& handler : handlerFList) {
                if (handler->handle(event)) {           // SEGFAULTS
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void TestApp::attach_handler(Handler* handler) {
    handlerFList.push_front(std::unique_ptr<Handler>(std::move(handler)));
    handler->application = this;
}

int main() {
    sqt::TestApp app;

    app.run();
    return 0;
}
```

It segfaults where marked. I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. Isn't std::move supposed to move the base object? What it seems like is happening is that once TestApp's constructor finishes, the object is getting deleted. How can I fix this?

Comment: _"Isn't std::move supposed to move the base object?"_ No, it's supposed to cast the argument to an rvalue, thereby settings things up _to be_ moved.

Comment: So, do I need to add some extra code to attatch_handler?

Comment: I'm lost. I don't know what you mean in regards to actually doing that move :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by doing `move` on a raw pointer. Could you explain your reasoning? It seems to me like your second piece of code is pushing a pointer to a `HandlerClose` object that will then immediately go out of scope and be destroyed.

Comment: That's the problem. I want to be able to define any (derived) kind of the class Handler, create it, then add it to the vector in TestApp. I want the attach_handler function to add the passed object to TestApp's Vector, and then it to last as long as testapp does (or I remove it through a remove_handler fuction)

Comment: And I don't want it to matter where the object is first defined/declared, it won't always be in the constructor of TestApp